# how to change a tag path convert to live server path with .next path after npm run build command

Tags: reactjs, next.js, build, next.js13, next-auth

after build generate my project index.html file **a** tag path was how to change live server domain slash after .next folder path how to set.

**.next/server/app/index.html**

[image]

attached image in a tag path how to change like live server path name with build path where the build works like

.next/server/app/index.html

href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/_next/server/app/staticroutername.html"

with .html extension.